# How to convert decimal to hex in Arduino library

Tags: arduino

I need to add a conversion from dec to hex in this function but failed.

```
    void AB1805::set_minute(const uint8_t value)
{
  _minute = value % MAX_MINUTE;
  write_rtc_register(MINUTE_REGISTER, _minute);
}
```

I tried

```
void AB1805::set_minute(const uint8_t value)
{
  _minute = value % MAX_MINUTE;
  write_rtc_register(MINUTE_REGISTER, dec_hex(_minute,2));
}

uint8_t AB1805::dec_hex(uint8_t tens, uint8_t digits)
{
  uint8_t ret;
  ret = (tens<<4) + digits;
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to BCD.  Clarify the results you want.  If you do that, the solution will likely become apparent.  In particular, what do you mean by "hex?"

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal and decimal notation are just two different ways to express the same value.

`set_minute(255);` is the exact same thing as `set_minute(0xFF);` or `set_minute(0b11111111);`

You only need to specify a format if you want a string representation of that number in a specific format. Not if you want to just use that value in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, RTCs store the data in BCD format

```
uint8_t toBCD(uint8_t val) {  // expects a value 0 .. 99 
  return (val%10 & 0x0F) | (val/10 << 4); // returns 0x00 .. 0x99
}
```

No error checking, as usual in the Arduino world.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean with no error checking and how would you improve it?

Comment: What, if val is not in the range 0 .. 99 ? Some values are only allowed to be 0..59 or even less, because there are other bits in the RTC - register.